Gradle run: getClass().getClassLoader().getResource() return Null
I'm trying to import a file to use in my simple Java project, I'm currently using IntelliJ as IDEE and Gradle to build the project.
Problem:
When I try to check if the program load the resources using
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(filePath);
function, passing "src/main/resources/File" as argument, it work fine, as I build the application (using Gradle) and run it via IntelliJ.
However, when I try to get it work with grade run via terminal, the task FAIL because it can't find the resource file, as the function return Null.
Here is my path tree:
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── java
│   │       └── main
│   │           └── it
│   │               └── uni
│   │                   └── cs
│   │                       └── name
│   │                           └── progettofinaledatemplate
│   │                               ├── controller
│   │                               ├── models
│   │                               └── view
│   ├── distributions
│   ├── generated
│   │   └── sources
│   │       ├── annotationProcessor
│   │       │   └── java
│   │       │       └── main
│   │       └── headers
│   │           └── java
│   │               └── main
│   ├── libs
│   ├── resources
│   │   └── main
│   │       └── it
│   │           └── uni
│   │               └── cs
│   │                   └── name
│   │                       └── progettofinaledatemplate->resources files
│   ├── scripts
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── compileTransaction
│       │       ├── backup-dir
│       │       └── stash-dir
│       └── jar
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── it
        │       └── uni
        │           └── cs
        │               └── name
        │                   └── progettofinaledatemplate
        │                       ├── controller
        │                       ├── models
        │                       └── view
        └── resources
            └── it
                └── uni
                    └── cs
                        └── name
                            └── progettofinaledatemplate->resources files

Sorry If I repeated an already existing topic, but I can't find any solution.
What I tried:

Verified the presence of the file in the filepath
rebuilt the project via Build > Rebuild Project
used an absolute path
tried to verify that grade included the resources with:

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }
}


Please use the preview to check your post's formatting before submitting it. I've edited it now, but it was unreadable before.

For a start, don't use the name "filePath" in getResource(filePath). Stop thinking of it as a file; it's a resource. When you build your application, whatever is in the resources directory is placed in the root of your jar file. You should be able to access your resource using getResource("/File") (that is, leave out the src/main/resources bit).

You almost never want to have that level of nesting in resources. There's no need to mirror your package tree

Thanks for the replies, I've used getResource("/FileName");  but still return Null. However this time running the application via IntelliJ will return Null value.
I'm positive that the problem is not regarding the resource format. Thanks again @k314159

You are using incorrect url for loading resources. Change the path of url location that will maturely serve your inquires . This is an answer to your prob.

It would help if you gave an actual file name rather than some sort of cryptic placeholder

It seems you're using the wrong name/path. Study carefully the documentation for Class.getResource and ClassLoader.getResource. Once you've absorbed all that information, you should be able to figure out your issue.

srcDir 'src/main/resources' is superfluous. That is already the default source directory for resources in the main source set. Also note that srcDir only adds a source directory, it doesn't replace any existing ones.

Let x.txt be a resource, sitting there as a leaf of your resource tree, and the class from which you're accessing it be called X. The code I would use is: URL u = X.class.getResource("/main/it/uni/cs/name/progettofinaledatemplate/x.txt"); Now you can see the reason for my comment about over-nesting

@g00se if the resource is in the same package under the resources directory as the class from which you're loading it, then you can leave out the package path. Thus there is some benefit in having resources under a package structure.

That's true. But that pattern is at least 'always' going to work so it's the first one I would cite

Note that ClassLoader::getResource only accepts absolute paths, but without any leading /. That's different from Class::getResource. And note the src/main/resources directory will never be part of that path (unless you're doing some strange and unconventional things). Consider the resources directory as a "root". Though also keep in mind that what truly matters when looking up resources is the class-path/module-path, not the source directories. By default, the run task will include build/resources/main on the class-path for non-modular projects.

Sorry, didn't mean to get cryptic.
To clarify, this is the specific path I use:
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("it/uni/cs/name/progettofinaledatemplate/Tracciato3.txt");

That uses Class::getResource. For that method, absolute paths are denoted by a leading /. If there is no leading / then the path is resolved relative to the class's location (i.e., its package). What happens if you put a leading /? Or what happens if you just use "Tracciato3.txt" (assuming the class returned by getClass() is in the it.uni.cs.name.progettofinaledatemplate package).

URL url = this.getClass().getResource("it/uni/cs/name/progettofinaledatemplate/Tracciato3.txt"); That would be ok if the package name of this is relatively correct. Personally I think it safer and less doubtful to use the absolute form I've already given

Solution that worked with my Application:
After hearing the many helpful tips, I removed the nesting of the resource files, given "Tracciato3.txt" the file name and X the class I used, I moved the "Tracciato3.txt" file from:
src/main/resources/it/uni/cs/name/progettofinaledatemplate/Tracciato3.txt

to
src/main/resources/Tracciato3.txt

now if I use
URL url = X.class.getClassLoader().getResource("Tracciato3.txt");

it doesn't return null, instead It get the correct URL.
It worked for me, so I hope this will be helpful

This will work, but it’s a terrible solution.  Resources are supposed to be in packages, for the same reason classes are in packages:  to minimize the likelihood of colliding with other libraries.
